# Proving that no neighborhood of $0$ lies within a set with only rational members

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Fix $0<\epsilon<\sqrt{2}$. I am trying to prove that no neighborhood of $0$ with radius $\epsilon$ can be a subset of E, where all members of $E$ are rational.

**Definition of density**:

> $E$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is either a limit point of $E$, or a point of $E$, or both.

**My argument so far**:
We know that the set of irrationals is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence also in any given proper subset of $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$. This means that for any given subset of $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$, we can find a point that is either irrational or is a limit point of the set of irrationals. If the point is irrational, we are done. However, I think the argument fails if the point is a limit point of the set of rationals, which might not be irrational itself. It seems obvious for a diagram, but I am having trouble in stating the idea in words. Any suggestions on how the same can be expressed rigorously?

Comment: What about points of the form $\sqrt{2}/2^n$?

Comment: How about proving any neighborhood of $0$ contains an irrational number by taking $\dfrac1{N\sqrt2}$, where  $N\in \mathbb N$ and $ N>\frac1\epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\ \epsilon>0\ $ is given.

- If $\epsilon$ is rational, the interval $(0,\epsilon)$ contains the irrational number $\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$
- If $\epsilon$ is irrational, the interval $(0,\epsilon)$ contains the irrational number $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

In both cases, the neighborhood contains at least one irrational number.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an open ball around $0$: $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and let $E\subset \mathbb{Q}$. We know that the irrationnals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so for every point $x\in\mathbb{R}$: $x$ is irrationnal or it exists a suit $x_n$ where $x_n\in\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\right)$ and $x_n\to x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Let's take the number $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ which is in our open ball.

- If $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is irrationnal we showed that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\not\subset E$
- If $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is rationnal there exists a suit $x_n\to \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ where $x_n\notin \mathbb{Q}$ (Density of irrationnals). So let's take such a suite. Since $x_n\to x$, and by the definition of convergence you can find $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such as $\forall n>N$, $|x_n-x|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$. So then every $x_n$ ($n>N$) is in your open ball $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $x_n\notin \mathbb{Q}$ by definition of $\{x_n\}$. So our ball contains irrationnals and is not a subset of $E\subset\mathbb{Q}$